# Put a file in a library with a File-Upload on sharepoint designer

Tags: 2013, javascript, file-upload, library, file

I work on SharePoint designer 2013 and I try to put a file(The file can be an image, a text file, a powerPoint, a videos or any type of file) in a library with a FileUpload.

I didn't find any code in JavaScript which allows to do that. But when I coded in C#, SharePoint returned an error message

> "Les blocs de code ne sont autorisés dans ce fichier"

or in english

> "Code blocks are not allowed in this file".

Can someone help me to find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In sharepoint Designer you cant Use c#,im not clear how did you do it,you need to go for webpart solution for this or another way,simple answer is you cant do serverside code with SPD.

below links might help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee330921%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396